# Why is my for-loop only prompting me once for an input?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement, event-listener

I want the user to be able to click the UP arrow 5 times and each time a separate startTime and endTime is logged. Thus the console will return how fast they responded (msResponse).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function touch(e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 38: 
                    var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                    var msResponse = endTime - startTime;
                    console.log(msResponse);
                    document.removeEventListener("keydown", touch);
                    break;
            }
        })};
```

I'm expecting that the loop will prompt me 5 times to click the UP arrow. Each time setting a new startTime and endTime.

However, the first time I click the UP arrow it loops through 5 times and the msResponse is increased ever so slightly with each loop iteration.

If anyone could help me understand this a bit better that would be amazing!

Many thanks!

Comment: `addEventListener` isn’t a prompt – it adds a function that runs every time a key is pressed, and it doesn’t pause your script while waiting for that to happen. You only need to add one listener, then remove it after it’s been pressed 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are for repetition and for creating new variables. Because your for loop isn't used other than to repeat your code, it ends up looking like this:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function touch(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38: 
                var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                var msResponse = endTime - startTime;
                console.log(msResponse);
                document.removeEventListener("keydown", touch);
                break;
        }
    })};

/*Main problem you mentioned in your question was that time is only increasing ever so slightly. You are reassigning startTime = new Date() in your second iteration.*/


var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function touch(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                var endTime = new Date().getTime();
                var msResponse = endTime - startTime;
                console.log(msResponse);
                document.removeEventListener("keydown", touch);
                break;
        }
    })};
```

I would create an array of times logged whenever the key is pressed and unbind the key when the array reaches.length = x.

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var endTime = [startTime];


window.addEventListener( "keydown", function touch(e) {
  if(endTime[5] !== undefined){
    window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', touch() );
  }else if ( e.keyCode === 38 ){
    var msResponses = new Date().getTime();
    endTime.push(msResponses);
  }
});
```

This code creates an array of numbers based on time, you can subtract them from the start to get the time since the function was called or from each other to get the difference between first press and second press, second and third. Or whatever.